# Meaning of: who is as market savvy as he was

Tags: grammar

I'm watching Warren Buffet's biography, but I can't hear clearly and I'm not sure if I am correct in this excerpt:

> "Warren Buffet had found Monger, who was a **market savvy as he was.**

Or

> Warren Buffet had found Monger, who was **as market savvy as he was.**

Which is correct? I just can't google this one because this is a grammar issue.

Comment: market savvy is being used as an adjective, we use as:  "as big as he was" and "as market savvy as he was"

Comment: It can't be the first one, unless you can tell us what "a market savvy" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warren buffet had found Monger, who was as market savvy as he was. - Correct

The use of as two times makes the phrase comparative  and here Buffet means - he had found somebody (Monger)  who was as good/interested in markets as he was.

Comment: Both are great answers, and I just learned another English rules below (Micheal Rybkin), however, this one fits my question better.

Comment: I don't think this rule really explains the whole problem very well. What if the sentence were: _Warren Buffet had found Monger, who was (as/a) savvy investor as he was._ The word "a" would work fine there, if the writer simply wanted to indicate that both parties were savvy investors.

Answer (score 1):

> Warren buffet had found Monger, who was **as market savvy as** he was.

Given the context, this one above is most likely to be the correct one because the construction *as ... as* is only used with adjectives and never with nouns. *Market savvy*, *computer savvy* etc. are very common adjective expressions in English. It's also entirely possible to use a hyphen with them, which will make them look like one big compound word: *market-savvy*, *computer-savvy* etc. That way they truly look like real adjectives if you think that two-word expressions with a space between individual words look suspicious to you as adjectives.

With regard to the meaning, I think it's going to be clear to see what *as market savvy as* means if you take a look at the following three example sentences:

> He is not as smart as you are. (meaning: you are smarter than he is)
>
> She is not as computer savvy as you are. (meaning: you are more computer savvy than her)
>
> He is as market savvy as I am. (meaning: we both have the same level of savvy when it comes to trading, marketing etc.)

Comment: but savvy is also listed as a noun in my dictionary. ex: *He's obviously got a lot of political savvy*. could you help to explain that observation? thanks!

Comment: @dan All I can say is that the word *savvy* can also be used as a noun, but the noun version of *savvy* is not really going to work in this case as it's, first of all, a mass noun while we need a countable noun here and secondly it doesn't seem to fit the semantics of the sentence either.

Comment: @dan: The noun sense of ***savvy*** corresponds to other "abstract" nouns such as ***nous, understanding, sense***. You can say things like *He **has** [a lot of] savvy / nous / understanding / sense*, but you can't say things like *He **is** [a] nous / understanding / sense*, because unlike ***savvy***, those alternatives can't also function as adjectives.

Comment: @dan - Interestingly enough, if we replace the word _savvy_ with _shark_, then we would use `a` instead of `as`. _Warren Buffet had found Monger, who was a market shark, as he was._ It all comes down to _as savvy as_ is a normal construct, but _a savvy_ is not. Excellent observation, though.